# Creating number of small small table or creating a very large table, which way is recommended in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

I have query regarding the performance of MySQL, that is

I have the mysql table with more than 60 columns now I have a requirement to add many more 
columns to that table. I am always bothering  about performance. So can you please tell me any body which way is best way. That is either creating the large table or creating a number of small small tables.

Answer (score 1):

small tables are best in performance and easy to recover the data.
so i am suggesting you can go for small tables and create relationship between them like primary key and foreign key or delete or update cascade as per your requirement.Always adding multiple columns to a table impact on your DB performance.

Answer (score 0):

Never use long flat table. Divide it into separate table. you need to learn how to design database. Just search google 'data normalization'